# Redux: Dynamically pass component to Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a function that dynamically accepts a component for a Provider. I could of course just add the store to the component, but for simplicity's sake I'd like to try to pass it via a function argument.

For example, I'd like to be able to dynamically create this by passing in `MyComponent`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={reduxStore}>
    <MyComponent />
  </Provider>,
  $('.my-component)[0]
)
```

This, however, no longer works as of React 0.14.

```
let provideComponent = function(selector, store, componentCallback) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      componentCallback()
    </Provider>,
    $(selector)[0]
  )
}

provideComponent('.my-component', reduxStore, function() {
  return <MyComponent />
}

# raises error
# Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
```

I've also tried adding the store to the component after it is passed in, but this is forbidden. How can I dynamically pass in a smart component to a Redux provider?

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea what you're trying to do here. More info?

Comment: @rossipedia I just updated how the function would by called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let provideComponent = function(selector, store, componentCallback) {
  var Component = componentCallback();

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component />
    </Provider>,    
    $(selector)[0]
  )
}

provideComponent('.my-component', reduxStore, function() {
  return MyComponent;
}
```

Remember, JSX is case-sensitive. Both upper case and lower case elements get translated to `React.createElement` calls. But upper case elements are treated as Components, and thus passed "naked", whereas lower case elements are treated as DOM elements and passed as strings:

```
<div>
  <Component />
</div>
```

gets translated to:

```
React.createElement('div', {},
  React.createElement(Component, {})
)
```

Notice `<div>` turns into `'div'` (quotes), whereas `<Component />` turns into `Component` (no quotes).

* EDIT *

If you want your callback to specify props, instead of passing them during the `ReactDOM.render()` call, you would do something like this:

```
let provideComponent = function(selector, store, componentCallback) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      {componentCallback()}
    </Provider>,    
    $(selector)[0]
  )
}

// Return the actual element, instead of just the type
provideComponent('.my-component', reduxStore, function() {
  return <MyComponent prop1="value" prop2="value" />;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. And how would I pass MyComponent with props?

Comment: Same as always: `<Component prop1="value" ... />`

Comment: Hm, the version with props doesn't seem to be working. I get the same error as in my example (just added the error)

Comment: You have the `$(selector)[0]` in the wrong spot. It needs to be passed as the _second_ argument to render, not as a child of `<Provider>`

Comment: Derp. This is working great, and I learned something. Thanks!